# Bootstrap Form Elements Not Level

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form and when place two text fields in a row the one is now level with the other. I removed the column, row classes, worked with using the form-group class, can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated.  [image: Phone and Email are not Level with one Another]

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="fld_1" name="fld_1" placeholder="Record ID" type="hidden">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fld_6" style="font-weight: bold">Customer Name</label> <input class="form-control" id="fld_6" name="fld_6" placeholder="Customer Name" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 column">
                <label for="fld_7">Phone</label> <input class="form-control" id="fld_7" name="fld_7" placeholder="Phone" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 column">
                <label for="fld_8">Email</label> <input class="form-control" id="fld_8" name="fld_8" placeholder="Email" type="email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Create New Customer</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<div class="col-md-6 column">` before `<div class="form-group">`

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yohLs3es/7/

Comment: Thank You! I knew it had to be something simple that i missed!